# UI is not fixed on painting the background in VerticalFieldManager in BlackBerry?

Tags: layout, blackberry

I have prepared a screen in which I am allowing user to create an account. as shown in the first image I have used an image(bg_BB.png image) as `MainScreen` Background, after that i have taken another VFM and painting that white Background (white_bg2.png)on that vertical field manager and ADDING ALL MY FIELD ON THAT VFM.

But the problem arises when the keyboard is pops-up. All the fields apears to be floating over the background as shown in the second pic.

Below is the code which I am using:

```java
Bitmap backGroundImage = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("bg_BB.png");
((VerticalFieldManager) getMainManager()).setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(backGroundImage));

final Bitmap tabBackGroundImage = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("white_bg2.png");

_mainVfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        int y = CreateUserAccountScreen.this.getMainManager().getVerticalScroll();
        graphics.drawBitmap(0, y, 
                            tabBackGroundImage.getWidth(), 
                            tabBackGroundImage.getHeight(), 
                            tabBackGroundImage, 
                            0, 0 );

        super.paint( graphics );
    }
};
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**replace your code with:**

```java
Bitmap tabBackGroundImage = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("white_bg2.png");
VerticalFieldManager _mainVfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | 
          Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR|
          Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
_mainVfm.setBorder( BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(
               new XYEdges(12,12,12,12), tabBackGroundImage
       )
);
```

make sure that your border image have white background. 
i use this method and it works perfectly.